# RegularExpressionValidator not firing on white-space entry

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to validate string containing only numbers.  Easy validation?  I added RegularExpressionValidator, with ValidationExpression="/d+".

Looks okay - but nothing validated when only space is entered!  Even many spaces are validated okay.  I don't need this to be mandatory.

I can trim on server, but cannot regular expression do everything!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design and tends to throw many people off. The RegularExpressionValidator does not make a field mandatory and allows it to be blank and accepts whitespaces. The \d+ format is correct. Even using ^\d+$ will result in the same problem of allowing whitespace. The only way to force this to disallow whitespace is to also include a RequiredFieldValidator to operate on the same control.

This is per the [RegularExpressionValidator documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx), which states:

> Validation succeeds if the input
>   control is empty. If a value is
>   required for the associated input
>   control, use a RequiredFieldValidator
>   control in addition to the
>   RegularExpressionValidator control.

A regular expression check of the field in the code-behind would work as expected; this is only an issue with the RegularExpressionValidator. So you could conceivably use a CustomValidator instead and say `args.IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(txtInput.Text, @"^\d+$")` and if it contained whitespace then it would return false. But if that's the case why not just use the RequiredFieldValidator per the documentation and avoid writing custom code? Also a CustomValidator means a mandatory postback (unless you specify a client validation script with equivalent javascript regex).

Comment: all whitespaces is considered empty?  looks like trim on the server is the answer.

Comment: Yes, leaving it blank or adding whitespace is the same. Once a character has been entered the validator will trigger, so entering " 10" is valid. You can keep it as it is, knowing that whatever makes it through will be a valid number or whitespace. In either case trim your value.

Comment: thanks Ahmad.  i wish MSDN docs would say "all whitespace is empty"!

Answer (score 1):

try to use Ajax FilteredTextbox, this will not allow space.......
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Comment: this is by design, if you want to disallow space, AJAX FilteredTextbox is best option......

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little hard to follow, but if you are asking how to write a regular expresion which only accepts digits I think your mistake is in using forward-slash instead of backslash. Try

`"\d+"`

Comment: yes, i have tried.  let me try explain.  
entering into text box: "55" - valid. 
"55x" - fails (this is good).  
"    " - valid! (not so good!)

Comment: Ok, in your example you said you used "/d+" which is very different then "\d+" in regex. Have you tried adding RequiredFieldValidator as well? This might prevent the " " as legal. Not 100% positive, I don't claim to be an asp.net expert ;)

Answer (score 1):

The RegularExpressionValidator is a nice wrapper for doing regex checks but it will not validate against an empty control. You could use a CustomValidator and then do the regular expression check in a javascript function that you attach to the validator.

It will validate against an empty (blank) control as long as you set the `ValidateEmptyText` property to true.

You can read more about the CustomValidators on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx.aspx).

Comment: To add to this, while a clientside script can be used with a CustomValidator it would be wise to also include server side validation to cover all bases.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ^\d+$ to force the digits to fill the entire line.
^ = line start $ = line end

Comment: IIRC, the ^ and $ are implicit when using a Regex validator.

Comment: I "assumed" that myself, but got bitten by unexpected matches in the past.  Oh, wait, that waas pure RegEx.  Not sure about the validator.