# Can I test if the first four characters in a string are letters?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to make sure the first 4 letters in a eight character code is a letter.

Is there a function for that, or do I have to make my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add javascript/regex validation like this:

```js
/^[a-zA-Z]{4}.*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [regular expression validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there's no built-in function. A *letter* might mean different things according to user culture. If you mean ASCII letter you could test like this:

```
bool IsASCIILetter(char letter) {
    return letter >= 65 && letter <= 90 && letter >= 97 && letter <= 122;
}
```

Comment: FYI - as of .net 7, there's [`Char.IsAsciiLetter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isasciiletter) which does exactly this

Comment: Also FYI - shouldn't *need* to use magic number constants to represent `a`, `z`, `A`, and `Z`.  Compiler actually turns them back into characters for comparison anyway [demo in sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQzABCBMEMIQN4FgBQENUgIwPa4BsIBJAZwEEBlOY4gGQFMAXJhgJwEYAKAYwAsAhmwgFmrNgEokaTLKgB2EWPYQAfAF4IANgCsEAGT6lLFQB5NATgAMBo6JPCNEC4sPHxEcxA7RoAbhlMAF9AjHAIPEISCmpaRgdoXkFhe3EpFHQ5MMVUlScAcnJ823czTXyALWK3XMdygWq7ZWEvfIAvfIDMjBDUIKA=)

Answer (score 1):

How about [Char.IsLetter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isletter.aspx)?

It has 2 overrides: one where you pass it a char and one where you pass it a string and index.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the contents of an input control you want to validate, use a [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx).

This case is probably simple enough to just use a RegEx, but for more complex validation I try to avoid RegExes as they are just too complex to debug. As somebody smarter than me said 'I had a problem which I solved with regular expressions. Now I have two problems'. Even if you are comfortable with regular expressions, the person who maintains your code might not be.

More explicit code is a lot easier to read and maintain:

```
bool IsValid (string code) {
    if (code.Length != 8)
        return false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (!Char.IsLetter(code[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

**Option 1** - Check for it in your code-behind:

```
    if (txtBox1.Text.Length >= 4 && txtBox1.Text.ToCharArray().Take(4).All(c => char.IsLetter(c)))
    {
        // success
    }
    else
    {
        // validation failed
    }
```

You didn't state whether you're enforcing a length of 8 or it's optional and *upto* 8. You can add this check fairly easily.

**Option 2** - Use a RegularExpressionValidator with an optional RequiredFieldValidator. If you decide to go this route you really should know exactly what you want to permit for the last 4 characters as this example below allows anything and only restricts the first 4 to letters. Also, again, this will differ if you wanted to enforce a length of 8 or not. This one below makes it mandatory; to make it optional to have 8 characters you would use "[A-Za-z]{4}(.{4})?" instead.

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

`<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvtxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ErrorMessage="txtBox1 is required!" Display="Dynamic">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

`<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revtxtBox1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtBox1" ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z]{4}.{4}" ErrorMessage="First 4 characters must be a letter!" Display="Dynamic" />`

A RequiredFieldValidator is needed if you don't want to allow a blank entry since the RegularExpressionValidator alone won't prevent blank/whitespace entries. For more info see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085464/regularexpressionvalidator-not-firing-on-white-space-entry/1085549#1085549).