# RegularExpressionValidator with Or statement

Tags: c#, regex, validation, webforms

I need to add some validation to a field that allows the user to enter either a single instance of the number 0, or a 10 to 11 digit phone number that's only allowed to be numbers.

I've come up with the following regex using an online tester, which would seem to work:

> ^0{1}$|^\d{10,11}$

But when I use it in my code like this:

```
foo= new RegularExpressionValidator()
{
    ControlToValidate = controlID,
    ValidationExpression = @"^0{1}$|^\d{10,11}$",
    ErrorMessage = "Invalid input.",
    Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic
};
```

The validation never fires. Previously it was just checking to make sure it was a 10 to 11 digit phone number of only numbers, and it worked fine, but adding the part to also allow for a single instance of the number 0 causes it to never fire.

So how can I get this handled?

EDIT: So I just did a bit of additional testing. It actually DOES seem to work, but if I leave the field completely blank it doesn't fire. Now I'm even more baffled....

Comment: You can shorten your regex to `^0$|^\d{10,100}$` - `{1}` does nothing in regex.

Comment: Maybe: `@"^(?:0|\d{10,11})$",`

Comment: @Samadi Gotcha, and you may want to edit your comment as you made it 10,100 in the last bit, and not 10,11. Copied it to test and it freaked me out to see I could go well beyond 11 digits. :P

Comment: @MattD, oops! I think SO puts a time limit on editing comments though, which I've just missed :-/

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes, that does the same thing, just with more characters

Comment: Updated the question. It DOES actually seem to be working, but doesn't fire when the field is 100% empty. Enter just a 1? Validation message is shown. Enter 0 or a valid phone number? Goes away. Completely empty the text field? Validation doesn't fire.

Comment: @MattD, that's _very_ odd. That regex should **definitely** not match an emtpy string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is here, basically a `RegularExpressionValidator` only tests a non-empty field, e.g. it does not make the field required. You must add a `RequiredFieldValidator`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085549/2557128

Comment: Yep, I came to that realization/workaround about 15 minutes ago, and it worked. Was just about to answer with the same thing, but since you got to it before I could you'll get all the points. :D