# How to make require fields in every text box in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I am creating a basic CRUD system, where you can register clients, and I want to make every textbox a required field, but I don't know how to do that.

Can someone help me ?

My code :

```
                <asp:BoundField DataField="cliente_id" HeaderText="Id do Cliente" ReadOnly="true" />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nome do Cliente">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblClienteNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_nome")%>'/>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtclienteNome" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_nome")%>'/>                       
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbnome" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "E-mail do Cliente">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblClienteEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_email")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtclienteEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_email")%>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbemail" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Data de Nascimento">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbldataNascimento" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_dataNascimento")%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtdataNascimento" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("cliente_dataNascimento")%>'/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>

                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtbdataNascimento" runat="server" />                        
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAdd" CommandName="AddNew" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-large btn-info pull-right"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> &nbsp; Adicionar</asp:LinkButton>   
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make one textbox required? Are you looking for how to make them all programmatically?

Comment: I am new to ASP.NET, and don't know how to make a textbox required. I need to make every textbox required.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do is using adding the following code under all the textbox

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqName" controltovalidate="textboxid" errormessage="Please enter your Value!" />
```

Comment: It's not working, I put the id from the textbox to the controltovalidate and don't work. Why is this happening ?

Comment: Two reasons might be 1. Use ControlToValidate property as Camel Case , 2. You are pre filling  the value in Textbox by using Text Property , to make it works try click on the cancel amount, it would work. If the value using Eval is null , then you have to use RegularExpression Validator to make sure the minimum length is entered.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085464/regularexpressionvalidator-not-firing-on-white-space-entry